# What can we do with Twilio api in iOS?

Tags: ios, iphone, twilio

I want to integrate **Twilio**  in my iOS app. I read **Twilio** documentation but I am getting confused on some points. I have few questions:

***Q 1) Can Twilio number receive messages from Mobile numbers (non twilio numbers)? Is it possible on trial Twilio number?***

I am trying to send SMS from Twilio verified **Indian** number(e.g.+919435XXXXXX) to my trial Twilio number. My message was not delivered to trial Twilio number. While I am able to send SMS form trial Twilio no. to my mobile number. Is reason is trial account or anything else?

***Q 2) Can we get two trial Twilio numbers for single account?***

***Q 3) How can send message using “Application url: https://hardw.herokuapp.com/"?***

This url got when we created app using following way https://www.twilio.com/docs/quickstart/php/ios-client/setup

I have trial account. I am able to call using this app url with the help of [BasicPhone](http://static.twilio.com/sdk/ios/twilioclient-ios-latest.tar.bz2) app. Now I want to send SMS using app url.
Currently I am sending sms as described here [Case 1: This is my native objective-c working code..](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31826787/how-to-make-twilio-api-post-request-with-the-help-of-afnetworking)

Please help me.Thanks...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Twilio Developer Evangelist here.

I'll try to answer your questions below:

1. Yes, a Twilio number is a number like any other, so you can send and receive SMS messages from any other number as well as making telephone calls. However, because you mentioned you're in India, it's worth [reading about the limitations in India](https://www.twilio.com/help/faq/sms/are-there-limitations-on-sending-sms-messages-to-indian-mobile-devices).
2. No, you can only have one number under a trial account, so in order to get more numbers you will need to upgrade your account, and put at least enough money to allow you to purchase a second number.
3. If all you want is to send SMS messages, all you need to have is a backend application that you can invoke via an HTTP request. That application will then make an API request to Twilio and send the SMS message. An example of how to send an SMS message can be found [here](https://www.twilio.com/docs/quickstart/php/sms/sending-via-rest).

Let me know if you have any other questions.

Comment: Thank you @Marcos, your answer is helpful for me.

Comment: No problem, let me know if there's anything else I can help with. I hope you manage to send SMS messages soon ;-) And make sure you mark the question as answered.

Comment: Can we get Indian trial number with country code +91 instead of +1 ?

Comment: If you get in touch with help@twilio.com, I'm pretty sure they will be able to change that for you